# Which is faster? Rendering partials or using if-statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, partial-views, benchmarking

I have a page that I am rendering which is going to look slightly different depending on who is viewing it. My two options are 1) use some `ifs` to only display the relevant info and 2) render two different views from my controller based upon who the user is.

In keeping things DRY, I don't want to just render two completely separate pages. Instead, I'd prefer that each page I render both refer to some common partials.

For example:

**Option 1**

`view.slim`

```
h1 Notifications
- if current_user.student.id == params[:id]
  = link_to 'Edit', ...
- @notifications.each do |note|
  # some stuff
h1 Activity
- if current_user.student.id == params[:id]
  = link_to 'Edit', ...
- @activities.each do |note|
  # some stuff
#etc...
```

**Option 2**

`current_user_view.slim`

```
= render 'notifications_header
= link_to 'Edit', ...
= render 'notifications'

= render 'activities_header
= link_to 'Edit', ...
= render 'activities'
```

`other_user_view.slim`

```
= render 'notifications_header
= render 'notifications'

= render 'activities_header
= render 'activities'
```

`_notifications.slim`

```
- @notifications.each do |note|
  # some stuff
```

Which is a more efficient approach?

**Benchmarks**

Here are some benchmarks I did with the following:

`_render.slim`

```
- 1000.times do
  = render 'foo'
```

`_foo.slim`

```
| Hello
```

`_if_clause.slim`

```
- 1000.times do
  - if current_user.student.id == params[:id]
    | Hello
```

With the following results:

[image: benchmarks]

So it appears as if rendering partials is extremely slow.

Thoughts?

Rails 4.1.5
ruby 2.1.2

Edit 1: Forgot to add the `| Hello` line in `_if_clause.slim`

Comment: I share your concerns... I had a case where I needed to render a nested tree (acts_as_nested_tree)... Everyone, even the documentation, stated that I should use recursion, rendering the same partial again and again.. I hated it. I ended up writing a recursive function, in view level, and do everything in there.. Much more efficient... Rendering a partial required disk access time, either from app tree or cache... Recursion and coding does everything in memory, so it should be faster, especially when dealing with large scales of repetition...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than say "Edit 1:", just blend the changes into the question naturally. We can see where you've changed the question if it every comes into question, and by blending it your question will make more sense. Also, rather than supply an image to show us text, simply copy/paste and format it in your question for readability. Links to external sites/sources always rot and break leaving gaps and nonsensical sections in a question. If you want to do benchmarks, use Ruby's built-in Benchmark class or use the Fruity gem. I recommend the later as it's easier to use.

Comment: @theTinMan hey, thanks for the tips! I used Ruby's Benchmark class originally. This data is coming from the `rack-mini-profiler` gem, as I wanted to actually get page load times as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your benchmark is not comparing the same functionality. The _render one is rendering 1000 partials with a string, the _if_clause one is doing only if-comparisons. You should compare e.g. a template rendering with inline notification handling and a template doing the notification handling in a partial.

But even if partial rendering should be much slower, the other thing to consider is, does it matter? Depending on your overall performance needs, it may be worth to sacrifice some milliseconds view time, if the code is easier to understand.

Comment: Good catch, but even adding the line (see my edit) in didn't change the times. In my opinion, using `ifs` is actually going to be much more readable.

Comment: Depending on the number of if-checks it may be easier to just do the if-check. If it gets too complicated, you could still refactor and extract some parts to partials.

Comment: It will be somewhere in the 8-12 range most likely. I was concerned that because my if has to hit the database, it would be slow, but I'm assuming Rails caches the result after the first time?

Comment: Yes, Rails is caching activerecord queries, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching for details